# Instrumentation for numerical linear algebra in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, instrumentation

I use numpy for numerical linear algebra. I suspect that I can get much better performance if I make small modifications in how I carry out certain computations so that they are more memory efficient, for example.

I was wondering if there is any form of instrumentation available in python to detect cache and TLB misses. There is a very nice api, PAPI, that I learned about in a recent class but it doesn't have a Python interface:

http://icl.cs.utk.edu/papi/overview/index.html

Also, is there a good way in general to profile numpy or other python numerical code? The timeit module is hard to integrate into code. mpi4py has a nice way to profile using the MPE library. A snippet from demo code (demo/mpe-logging/cpilog.py):

```
communication   = MPE.newLogState("Comunicate",  "red")
with communication:
    comm.Bcast([n, MPI.INT], root=0)
```

A log file is created that can be displayed graphically. But this is a bit MPI specific.

Thanks.

Comment: On the "better performance" part of your question,
what are you actually doing -- what numpy functions, what vec / array sizes, what cache size ?

Comment: Mostly dense matrix multiply with matrix sizes ranging from cache size to much larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert Kern (one of the NumPy devs) wrote [line_profiler](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/) for exactly this scenario. It is more suited to profiling NumPy-heavy code than hotspot/cProfile.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe one of the provided profilers might help you find the hotspots?

see [profiling python](http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html)

These will probably not give enough detail to trigger direct action, but should indicate where to look for improvement and help to determine the point of diminishing returns.